# Angular 13 MSAL Authentication Redirect Login

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, msal-angular

I'm trying to develop a project using Angular 13 - ngrx  & angular/msal with redirection
I have setup ngrx - actions, reducers, effects, selectors.
When, in landing page is going into infinite loop of msal redirection login, I'm unable to fix it,

 below is the code. 
**login.action.ts**

```
export const checkAuth = createAction('[Login] CheckAuth');

export const checkAuthComplete = createAction('[Login] checkAuthComplete', props<{ isLoggedIn: boolean }>())

export const loginAction = createAction('[Login] loginUser');

export const loginSuccessAction = createAction('[Login] loginSuccess', props<{ profile: AccountInfo; isLoggedIn: boolean }>());

export const logoutAction = createAction('[Login] logoutUser');

export const logoutComplete = createAction('[Login] logoutComplete');

export const acquireTokenSilent = createAction('[Login] loginToken', props<{ userToken: any }>());
```

**login.reducer.ts**

```
export const loginFeatureKey = "PokemonAuth";
//// State
export interface ILoginState {
    isAuthenticated: boolean;
    AuthUser?: AccountInfo
}

export const initialState: ILoginState = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    AuthUser: undefined
}

export const LoginReducer = createReducer(
    initialState,
    on(loginAction, (state, action) => ({
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: state.isAuthenticated,
        AuthUser: state.AuthUser
    })),
    on(loginSuccessAction, (state, action) => ({
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: action.isLoggedIn,
        AuthUser: action.profile
    })),

    on(logoutAction, (state, action) => ({
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        AuthUser: undefined
    }))
)
```

**login.effect.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginEffects {
    constructor(
        private actions$: Actions,
        private authService: MsalService,
        private router: Router) {

    }
    login$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(loginAction),
        switchMap(action => this.authService.loginRedirect()),
        map(data => loginSuccessAction({ isLoggedIn: true })),
        tap(data => checkAuthComplete({ isLoggedIn: true }))
    ));

    logout$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType('[Login] Lgout User'),
        mergeMap(() => this.authService.logoutRedirect()
            .pipe(
                map(logout_user => ({ type: '[Login] Logout User', payload: logout_user })),
                catchError(() => of({ type: '[Login] Loout Error' }))
            )
        )
    ));

}
```

**login.selector.ts**

```
export const SelectLoginFeatureState = createFeatureSelector<ILoginState>(loginFeatureKey);

export const selecteIsAuthenticated = createSelector(
    SelectLoginFeatureState,
    (state: ILoginState) => state.isAuthenticated);

export const selectAccountInfo = createSelector(
    SelectLoginFeatureState,
    (state:ILoginState)=>state.AuthUser)
```

**appcomponent.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'swordfish-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {


  isAuthenticated!: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(private store: Store) {
    this.store.dispatch(checkAuth());
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isAuthenticated = this.store.pipe(select(selecteIsAuthenticated));
    debugger;
    this.store.dispatch(loginAction())
  }

}
<div *ngIf="isAuthenticated | async as isAuthenticated; else noAuth">
    <div style="margin:5px;">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <header></header>
</div>

<ng-template #noAuth>
    <div>Please Login</div>
</ng-template>
```

Here, expected behavior when user launches webbrowser it should redirect to msal login page and after successfull login header should be displayed, and user navigates to respective links.

Comment: Also looking for a solution to this problem. It appeared to fix itself as long as you have all cookies allowed in chrome settings...

Comment: Looking at browser is not valid fix..

Comment: That's correct, hence why I didn't provide it as an answer. Just passing the suggestion along as a workaround if it's getting in the way of critical apps.

Comment: Yes I too got your point but I need to get a solution in next few days

Comment: What version of msal are you using?

Comment: @JoshuaTerrill I'm using the latest version
  "@azure/msal-angular": "^2.1.2",
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.22.1",

Comment: Are you using implicit flow? See this comment in the npm repo of msal-browser: "The current @azure/msal-angular library improves upon the previous version and utilizes the authorization code flow. Most features available in the old library will be available in this one, but there are nuances to the authentication flow in both. The latest @azure/msal-angular package does NOT support the implicit flow."

Comment: @JoshuaTerrill Yes Im tyring to use implicit flow

Comment: As pointed out above, the latest version of the msal-angular library that you're using does not support implicit flow.